# Is there any genus one knot other than $5_2$ with Alexander polynomial $2t^2-3t+2$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, alexander-polynomial

It is known that genus one fibred knots are two trefoils and the figure-eight knot. Is there any characterization of the knot $5_2$? Specifically, is there any other genus one knot that shares the same Alexander polynomial $2t^2-3t+2$ with $5_2$?

Comment: Yes, there should be plenty. Think of the Seifert surface for the 5_2 knot as a disk with two strips (1-handles) attached. By tying knots into the strips (with zero framing so as not to change the linking form), you can obtain many knots with a genus 1 Sefert surface with the same Seifert form and hence same Alexander polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ian Agol, in the comments says:

> Yes, there should be plenty. Think of the Seifert surface for the 5_2
> knot as a disk with two strips (1-handles) attached. By tying knots
> into the strips (with zero framing so as not to change the linking
> form), you can obtain many knots with a genus 1 Sefert surface with
> the same Seifert form and hence same Alexander polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

For the prime knot example, the first in the tables is $15n43522$ with diagram:

[image: knot diagram]

Answer (score 4):

I finally joined MO this evening to ask an entirely unrelated question, but I thought I might respond to this one as well. The Alexander polynomial does not detect $5_2$, as noted in the previous answers. However, we now know that both knot Floer homology and Khovanov homology detect this knot, as shown in my recent paper with Steven Sivek:

*Floer homology and non-fibered knot detection*, https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.03307.

Since knotMJ mentioned the hyperbolic knot $15n43522$, I'll point out that we also showed that knot Floer homology detects membership in the set

$\{15n43522, Wh^-(T_{2,3},2)\}$

where $Wh^-(T_{2,3},2)$ is the negatively-clasped 2-twisted Whitehead double of the right-handed trefoil. Knot Floer homology doesn't distinguish these two knots. It does, however, detect the *positively*-clasped 2-twisted Whitehead double of the right-handed trefoil $Wh^+(T_{2,3},2)$, as we prove in the paper.

These results follow from a classification of genus-1 knots in the 3-sphere whose knot Floer homology is 2-dimensional in the top Alexander grading (we call these knots *nearly-fibered*, as having 1-dimensional Floer homology in the top Alexander grading implies that the knot is fibered, by work of Ghiggini and Ni).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a different approach but having the same flavor: Take a (untwisted) Whitehead double of any nontrivial knot $K$. Denote such a double knot $WD(K)$. Construct a satellite knot using $5_2$ knot as the pattern and $WD(K)$ as the companion. Then the Alexander polynomial of the satellite knot is the product of the Alexander polynomials of $5_2$ knot and $WD(K)$. The latter has the trivial Alexander polynomial.